# Gráfico barras ggplot no R

Tags: r, ggplot2

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu gostaria de saber como retirar essas letras `a` que aparecem na legenda do gráfico de barras no ggplot no R. Quero que fique com os valores nas barras da mesma forma que aparece na imagem, mas quando rodo o código, esses `a` aparecem automaticamente na legenda.

Código:

```
CS = data.frame(
  Setores = factor(c("Comércio","Comércio","Serviços","Serviços")),
  Situação = factor(c("Admitidos","Desligados","Admitidos","Desligados"), 
                    levels=c("Admitidos","Desligados")),
  Quantidade = c(2604, -1766, 6826, -5331)

)

ggplot(data=CS, aes(x=Situação, y=Quantidade, fill=Setores)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = Setores), stat="identity", position="dodge") +
  geom_label(aes(label =round(Quantidade,0), group = Setores),
             colour = "black", position = position_dodge(width=1))
```

Answer (score 4):

Basta colocar o argumento `show.legend = FALSE` dentro da função `geom_label`:

```
ggplot(data=CS, aes(x=Situação, y=Quantidade, fill=Setores)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = Setores), stat="identity", position="dodge") +
  geom_label(aes(label =round(Quantidade,0), group = Setores),
             colour = "black", position = position_dodge(width=1),
             show.legend = FALSE)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Muito obrigada!!

Comment: É muito bom saber que a minha resposta te ajudou de alguma forma. Por isso, considere [votar e aceitar a resposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta), de modo que, no futuro, outras pessoas que passarem pelo mesmo problema tenham uma referência para solucioná-lo.